# Refractive index of air & pressure relation

Tags: optics, pressure, refraction

I do not understand why refractive index of air,when nearly equal to 1,is proportional to the pressure of the air.
If anybody can provide an answer with proper resource from which I can study on the matter,do help me.

Comment: It is $n - 1$ that is proportional to pressure, where $n$ is the refractive index.

Comment: That much I know,but what is the underlying law that says such relation between pressure & refraction

Answer (score 0):

The outer electron orbitals in a gas are susceptible to alteration in an applied field, sometimes called Stark effect.   Those molecules
can be   polarized, in proportion to the number of outer electrons.
By the usual (dilute gas) law, PV = nRT, we see that high pressure
means increase in 'n/V', the molar concentration.   Thus,
the deviation from no response (index  of refraction of vacuum :== 1.0)
is proportional to pressure, because the population density of gas
molecules is proportional to pressure, and the polarization response
of molecules gives rise to larger response when there are more molecules.